# Broken packages from versions mismatch

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

I've been trying to fix some dependencies to install cinelerra, and stupidly install libvpx1:amd64 for Sid and it casued a broken package. Synaptic could not fix it. I tried `apt-get install -f` and it gave me the following:

```
ZHD ~ # apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvpx1 : Breaks: libvpx1:i386 (!= 1.3.0-2) but 1.2.0-2 is installed
 libvpx1:i386 : Breaks: libvpx1 (!= 1.2.0-2) but 1.3.0-2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I've tried removing libvpx1:amd64, and it says it cannot because libvpx1:i386 is a different version. I've tried the other way round by removing libvpx1:i386, and it says it cannot because libvpx1:amd64 is a different version. I cannot downgrade or upgrade either of these packages to try and make them the same version.

If anyone has some suggestions I'd be glad to hear!

Aptitude gives some solutions, but involves uninstalling half of my software....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on this page:

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution

After trying

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

`sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status`    (you can use vi or gedit instead of nano)

Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

I then ran `sudo apt-get update && upgrade`

and it asked to install the missing package. 
Everything is running good now, and I've learnt not to so boldy install packages from other releases....

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution!

Comment: @ThomWiggers thanks for the pointer - but how??

Comment: Click on the empty checkmark next to the vote buttons.

Answer (score 3):

You installed mismatching versions of the same library in different architectures (amd64, i386). This isn't allowed.

To fix this, either run `sudo apt-get install -f libvpx1:i386=1.3.0-2` or `sudo apt-get install -f libvpx1=1.2.0-2`. The former command will bump up libvpx1:i386 to the version in Sid, and the latter command will bump down libvpx1:amd64 to the i386 version (Wheezy? Jessie?).

Comment: I tried to downgrade libvpx1:amd64, it gave me this response 

Unpacking replacement libvpx1:amd64 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libvpx1_1.2.0-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libvpx1/AUTHORS', which is different from other instances of package libvpx1:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvpx1_1.2.0-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Zebulun: Umm...what was the response?

Answer (score 0):

It happened because probably you installed two separate versions of apt out of which one was incompatible. Hence find out which is the architecture version of your system and remove the other package using the folowing steps:
You'll need to edit the dpkg file status manually.

1. Execute the following command :

> $ sudo nano/var/lib/dpkg/status

(You can use any other editor instead of nano(like gedit,vi, etc...)

2. Search for "Package: libapt-pkg" in the file that opens up.
3. if you find multiple segments with the same name, cut all of it out,store it in file and leave the appropriate one .
4. Save the file there itself and proceed with casual aptcommands.
5. If the error persists, Go for exchanging the "Package: libapt-pkg" block with another one from the file you've copied.